# Creating different views for pages, am I going about this the right/rails way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, routes

Rails noob here looking for some advice/direction on something. I have several "Pages" and I want to create different views of those pages. (e.g. - List view (text listing), gallery view (thumbnails), etc)

But the way I'm going about it doesn't seem DRY, but I'm new to Rails so I don't know.

Here's my setup. **routes.rb** I have:

```
resources :pages do
    collection do
         get :gallery
    end
    collection do
        get :list
    end     
end
```

In my **pages_controller.rb**

```
def gallery
  @pages = Page.find(:all, :order => "created_at")
end

def list
  @pages = Page.find(:all, :order => "created_at")
end
```

So already that seems strange because I'm duplicating the code between list and gallery.

In **views/pages/gallery.html.erb**

```
<% for page in @pages %>
    <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #DDD;float:left;margin:10px;">     
        <%= link_to page.name, page %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

In **views/pages/list.html.erb**

```
<% for page in @pages %>
    <div style="width:90%;border-bottom:1px solid #DDD;margin:10px;">
        <h3><%= link_to page.name, page %></h3>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Everything works properly. I see the list view when I go to http://localhost:3000/pages/list and the gallery view at http://localhost:3000/pages/gallery. But is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you could change your routes code a little. Not really necessary to specify collection twice:

```
resources :pages do
  collection do
    get :gallery
    get :list
  end     
end
```

And to avoid repeating your code in the controller, you could separate the Page.find code into a new method that gets called from a before_filter, something like this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_pages, :only => [:gallery, :list]

  def gallery
  end

  def list
  end

private
  def find_pages
    @pages = Page.find(:all, :order => "created_at")
  end
```

Those are the things I would start with improving. The views are not as important to consolidate in your case since thats where the mayor differences are going to be I assume.

Comment: Much appreciated, just the type of advice/validation I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the duplication of data in view file you can also create a partial file and can render that partial file in both of your view page.

Can be done in this way.

Create a partial file, suppose _page.html.erb

```
<% for page in @pages %>
    <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #DDD;float:left;margin:10px;">     
        <%= link_to page.name, page %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

and then you can render this file in your view page

in views/pages/gallery.html.erb

```
`<%= render :partial => 'page'%>
```

in views/pages/list.html.erb

```
`<%= render :partial => 'page'%>
```

And for routes and controller, I think @DanneManne have suggested the right way.

Hope this might solve your problem.